# Referencing to "above" or "below"?

Tags: cross-referencing

I would like to know if it is good practice, and if so how it can be achieved, to make references like: "as mentioned *above*...". Or am I going too far and should just type the word?

I've read something about `varioref`, but it seems to produce page or section numbers, but I can't find how you can just print if a section is above or below the reference.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can also implement the labels yourself by having labels define a flag and references check the flag existence. Some additional bookkeeping is needed to warn about undefined labels.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcount\here@undef
\newcommand{\here}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{here@#1@undef}{}{\advance\here@undef by -1}%
  \@namedef{here@#1}{}}
\newcommand{\where}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{here@#1}{%
    below%
    \@ifundefined{here@#1@undef}{%
      \@namedef{here@#1@undef}{}%
      \advance\here@undef by 1
    }{}%
  }{%
    above%
  }%
}
\AtEndDocument{%
  \ifnum\here@undef>0
    \GenericWarning{}{There were undefined above/below labels}%
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

As mentioned \where{test}, $2+2=4$.

We state that $2+2=4$.\here{test}

As mentioned \where{test}, $2+2=4$.

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I find it so strange that everything needs some extra programming and that such simple things that are easily found in word (shouldn't mention that here maybe `;)`) are still undefined in Latex. This looks like a nice solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Marnix: This likely means that the feature is not widely used. Most people will not be arbitrarily moving text blocks after they write them, so there is no need for a programmatic choice: you write either _above_ or _below_ directly. Besides, such references are  only useful at short distances, hence what `varioref` does in Daniel's answer.

Comment: @Andrey: Would it not be better to just patch the label command (or use `\myspeciallabel` instead of `\label') and have that do what \here does now? Otherwise, you would need to add a \here command to many labels.

Comment: @EyalRozenberg: Yes, it could be done so.

Comment: Do you know why this doesn't work when the \here{...} command is put inside minipages, and where is used outside the minipage?

Comment: @Marnix, conversely I suspect that one reason many prefer latex to word is precisely because they *can* write code like this to do just about anything, whereas in word it has to be a 'feature'.

Answer (score 21):

`varioref` can in fact do this you just need to give its `\vpageref` command a hint what to write to refer to an element on the same page. From the documentation:

> But in fact `\vpageref` allows even more control. If has two optional arguments.
>   With the first one, one can specify the **text that should be used if label and reference fall on the same page**. This is very helpful if both are near to each other, so that they may or may not be separated by a page break. In such a case we usually know (!) whether the reference is before or after the label so that we can say something like
>   ... see the example `\vpageref[above]{ex:foo}` which shows ...
>   which   will    then    come    out as  “. . .  see the example **above**   which   shows   . . . ”

The point is that if there is a page break in between the label and the element, `\vpageref` will notice this and insert something like *on the previous page* instead.

Comment: After reading the documentation, it sounds quite certain that it will produce `above` when the page and the label are on the same page. But what if I always want to use `above` and `below`. This only seems to specify `above` assuming that the label is above the reference. I can't make this assumption.

Comment: I'd like to come back to this. What I'd like to achieve is that references to a chapter come with an arrow whose direction depends on whether the referenced chapter is above or below (←/→ chapter 2). Neither the accepted solution nor `varioref` does allow this kind of automatic switching between 'above' and 'below'.

Comment: @Simifilm: Please consider asking this as a dedicated question, including a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I have asked it as a dedicted question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646462/how-to-add-a-hint-arrow-up-down-at-the-reference-for-direction-in-which-to-loo 

I was just referenced to this question/threads by a comment there...

Answer (score 6):

You can check the y-coordinate of a mark on a page and perform a comparison to decide whether you should print `above` or `below`. [`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s `savepos` module can help with that:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zref-savepos}

\newcounter{whereq}
\newcommand{\location}[1]{\zsaveposy{#1}}
\newcommand{\where}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{whereq}% New "where" request
  \location{whereq-\thewhereq}% Mark location
  % Test location based on y-coordinate
  \ifdim\zposy{whereq-\thewhereq}sp<\zposy{#1}sp
    above%
  \else
    below%
  \fi}

\begin{document}

As mentioned \where{test}, $2+2=4$.

We state that $2+2=4$.\location{test}

As mentioned \where{test}, $2+2=4$.

\end{document}
```

Of course, the above doesn't really care what page you perform the `\location` and `\where` macros on. However, it could be extended to condition on the page number as well.

Comment: This answer has an important advantage over the accepted answer: it works even if what is referenced is in a float. For example, wrap `We state that $2+2=4$.\location{test}` in `\begin{figure}[b]` ... `\end{figure}` and it will say "below" in both cases. If you change the `b` to `t` or `h` it still behaves correctly.

Comment: @Werner I hope, I am not lazy by asking you to write the full command `\where` and `\location` with the additional condition on the page number. It'd be so nice to have the **full answer**! :)

Comment: @Werner It doesn't work when the figure/table is on the next page while the `\where{}` is at the bottom of the current page.
It says that 'Table 1 above ...' while the table is located on the next page!

Comment: @FujiSan: Indeed! My current solution just considered the y coordinate between the two references (the location of the reference and the location of the `\where`). It should also consider what *page* the references are on. What should the output be for a reference that occurs on some page *before*/*after* `\where`?