# Automatic switching of arrows in references

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I would like to use references in a way that an arrow is in front of the referenc and points in the direction depending on whether the referenced instance is a above or below the reference (→ chapter 5).

Using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32285/referencing-to-above-or-below) I came up with the following solution.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\makeatletter
\newcount\here@undef
\newcommand{\here}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{here@#1@undef}{}{\advance\here@undef by -1}%
  \@namedef{here@#1}{}
  \label{#1}}
\newcommand{\where}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{here@#1}{%
    $\rightarrow$~\cref{#1}%
    \@ifundefined{here@#1@undef}{%
      \@namedef{here@#1@undef}{}%
      \advance\here@undef by 1
    }{}%
  }{%
    $\leftarrow$~\cref{#1}%
  }%
}
\AtEndDocument{%
  \ifnum\here@undef>0
    \GenericWarning{}{There were undefined above/below labels}%
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{one}
As we will see (\where{chap:one}).

\chapter{two}\here{chap:one}
This is some text. 

\chapter{three}
As we have seen (\where{chap:one})

\end{document}
```

While this seems to work and produces the desired result, I'm wondering whether there isn't a more elegant solution with an existing package (neither 'varioref' nor 'cleveref' seem to do the trick).

EDIT: I'd prefer a solution where I don't need to use two different kind of labels depending on the referencing style I use. I hesitate to redefine the `\label` command though.

Comment: This is a neat idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please let me know if this doesn't answer your question, or if it doesn't suit your need (and I will remove it).  You say you hesitate to redefine `\label`, but there is a compromise solution, in which `\label` is, technically, redefined, but (hopefully) in a way which preserves the original character when needed.

I am referring to the notion of saving a copy of the original: `\let\svlabel\label` and then redefining in a way which uses the saved original plus does a little extra innocuous stuff that doesn't break anything else.

Here's what I propose:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\makeatletter
\newcount\here@undef
\let\svlabel\label
\let\svcref\cref
\renewcommand{\label}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{here@#1@undef}{}{\advance\here@undef by -1}%
  \@namedef{here@#1}{}
  \svlabel{#1}}
\renewcommand{\cref}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{here@#1}{%
    $\rightarrow$~\svcref{#1}%
    \@ifundefined{here@#1@undef}{%
      \@namedef{here@#1@undef}{}%
      \advance\here@undef by 1
    }{}%
  }{%
    $\leftarrow$~\svcref{#1}%
  }%
}
\AtEndDocument{%
  \ifnum\here@undef>0
    \GenericWarning{}{There were undefined above/below labels}%
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{one}
As we will see (\cref{chap:one}).

\chapter{two}\label{chap:one}
This is some text. 

\chapter{three}
As we have seen (\cref{chap:one})

\begin{table}
\begin{center}Table\caption{Caption\label{tb:one}}\end{center}
\end{table}

In \svcref{tb:one} using original \verb|\svcref| and in
\cref{tb:one} using the revised \verb|\cref|.

Output is correct, though redefined \verb|\cref| of table generates
undefined labels.

\end{document}
```

In this way, one uses the familiar `\label` and `\cref` in the document (you could make it `\ref` if you preferred).  When you used a style that didn't use this arrow scheme, just remove the redefinitions.  The one side effect is that *all* `\cref` invocations will produce this arrow scheme (i.e., for figures, equations, and tables, not just sections).  But if your goal was to avoid that for these non-section entities, then you are back to the notion of having two separate commands, depending on the `\cref` type.

Also, while redefining `\label` produced no ill effects when using it for other labeling entities, redefining the `\cref` did produce undefined label warnings, even though the output appears to be correct.

If you don't like all the particulars of this approach, you also have the option of redefining just the usage of `\label`, but leaving `\where` as a separate command.  That would avoid the undefined label warnings, would allow the use of a single `\label` command, but would require two types of references, with or without arrow.

Finally, you could make your `\here` and `\where` just print an arrow, without the associated `\label` and `\cref`.  It would make your document syntax a bit longer, but would allow you to define `\here` and `\where` as `{}` when you wanted to turn them off, without affecting the rest of the document.