# Modified \pageref

Tags: cross-referencing

I want to modify `\pageref{...}` to cite the actual label page number if it is not on the same page (to where the command is called), or to state 'On the present page' if it is, how can this be done?

Furthermore, is it possible to state 'Above, on the present page' or 'Below, on the present page' depending on the relative location of the label to where the command was called....

Comment: See [Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36295) and [`varioref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/varioref), which I don’t have any firsthand experience with though.

Comment: Also, a more descriptive title would be great.

Comment: Please have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32285/referencing-to-above-or-below/32286#32286 which might be an exact duplicate.

Comment: Yep, its exact duplicate, may as well delete. @doncherry, next time, I'll endeavor to use fewer characters in the title.

Comment: @Daniel: It's not an exact duplicate: the other question doesn't ask for, and the answers don't deal with, matters of which page or treating this page as special, only the before/after relation.

Comment: @ADP Your good will is appreciated.