# Let's get it just right: An \aboveorbelow{some-label} command

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, automation

I would like to define an `\aboveorbelow` command which can be used as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Animals}
\label{sec:animals}
\section{Another section}
The quick brown fox (from \ref{sec:animals} \aboveorbelow{sec:animals})
jumped over the lazy dog.

The quick brown fox (from \ref{sec:plants} \aboveorbelow{sec:plants})
jumped over the lazy dog.
\section{Plants}
\label{sec:plants}
\end{document}
```

and will produce "above" if the label with identifier equal to the argument appears earlier in the document than  the invocation of `\aboveorbelow`, "below" if it appears later, and something else if it is missing.

How would I do that while properly recognizing intra-page references?

---

In the related question [Referencing to "above" or "below"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32285/referencing-to-above-or-below) two solutions require specific extra-labeling (e.g. with a `\here` or `\location` command); another one uses the `varioref` package, but will apparently fail for labels on the same page as the reference. I would rather use existing labels without having to create new ones, and preferably without having to patch the label command with `etoolbox` or anything like that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I've been using \autoref rather than \ref for so long I tend to forget it's a hyperref command. Edited.

Comment: if you had provided a test file (still not done) there would be nothing to remember as then you can easily check that the file runs.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: (sigh) ok, ok.

Comment: thanks, it really does help (not for this question for me by now, but in general)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{zzz}

\makeatletter
\def\aboveorbelow#1{%
\stepcounter{zzz}%
\edef\zztmp{\xdef\string\zzz\Roman{zzz}}%
\write\@auxout\expandafter{\zztmp{\string\@ifundefined{r@#1}{below}{above}}}%
\csname zzz\Roman{zzz}\endcsname}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section{Animals}
\label{sec:animals}
% etc. etc.
\section{Another section}
The quick brown fox (from \ref{sec:animals} \aboveorbelow{sec:animals})
jumped over the lazy dog.

The quick brown fox (from \ref{sec:plants} \aboveorbelow{sec:plants})
jumped over the lazy dog.

\section{Plants}
\label{sec:plants}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So, I understand putting an "if undefined" in the aux file. But - why do we need to use a counter for this?

Comment: @einpoklum look in the aux file you need to make a unique command defined to above or below for each use, the counter just arranges that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I took the liberty of adding an eol `%` before egreg spotted it, I hope it's ok. Pretty cool answer, thanks!

Comment: @gusbrs cruel, removing egreg's one pleasure in life.